# How to reset escalations on responses in OTRS?

Tags: otrs

Having OTRS queues to run escalations are fine. The thing is, that the tickets stay escalated if the solution time is exceeded.
The thing is sometimes it is a client responsibility to deliver something to close the ticket.
In this case the client gets a response.

How can I reset the escalation time to the time the ticket is replied and the pending is set to a specific date?
So the escalation time will occur e.g. 1 day after the pending date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check https://www.znuny.com/add-ons/znuny4otrs-repository and follow the instructions. After this the package is available the package manager

Answer (score 0):

try the free add-on Znuny4OTRS-EscalationSuspend. Then you can configure states where escalations are suspended. E.g. a state like 'pending customer feedback'

Comment: do you mean this?
https://opar.perl-services.de/package/Z/ZN/ZNUNY/Znuny4OTRS-EscalationSuspend
if so, it is from 2013 with no update so far. Does it still work on the 5.x OTRS?